# 2D vector, overlapping & different types of objects in array

Tags: c++, class, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm currently pondering how should I go about making a 2D vector array for a sort of a game board.

The board should be vectors because the size can vary, and each "square" should contain information about what objects are in that square.

The problem is that there can be overlapping objects, and the objects may not be the same type or class.

This is what I'm currently considering: (pseudo code)

```
struct Square {
    vector<enum type>;
    vector<pointers to objects>;
};

vector< vector <Square> >;
```

And the pointer's would point to different vector arrays each holding specific objects.

I'm unsure how to make such functionality or if this is even possible, and I'm seriously thinking this might be more complicated then it needs to be..

Some objects must be classes, but I could make all the types of objects in the game board classes that inherit from one master class.. But in the end the objects are completely different so I'm not sure if that makes much of a difference.

Am I just being blind and missing a easier way to do what I'm trying to do: 2D array holding different types of elements that can also overlap in the array?

I'd really appreciate any help, snippets or insight.

Notes: 
Board size won't chance after creation.
Objects must be able to move around in the board.

Comment: Can the size of the game board be changed after a game board has been created, or do you just mean that you'll need boards of different sizes?

Comment: No, the board size won't chance after creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class GameObject {
  public:
    virtual ~GameObject() {}

    enum Type {
       FOO,
       BAR
    };
    virtual Type type() const = 0;

    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual void damaged() {}
};

class FooObject : public GameObject {
  public:
     Type type() const { return FOO; }

     std::string name() const { return "Foo object"; }
     void damaged() {
        std::cout << "Foo was damaged!" << std::endl;
     }
};

class BarObject : public GameObject {
  public:
     Type type() const { return BAR; }

     std::string name() const { return "Bar object"; }
     // Bar object doesn't respond to damage: no need to override damaged()
};

class Square {
   std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<GameObject> > objects;
};

class Board {
   // Details of the implementation here not important, but there
   // should be a class to hide them.

   Square* squares;
   int width, height;

   Board(int width, int height) :
     squares ( new Square[ width * height ] ),
     width ( width ),
     height ( height )
   {
   }

   ~Board() {
      delete [] squares;
    }

   Square& square(int x, int y) {
      if( x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height ) {
          throw std::logic_error( "accessed square out of bounds" );
      }
      return squares[ x + width * y ];
   }
};
```

Summary:

- Have a single base class for all sorts of objects that can be placed on a game board.
- A class of this type must have a virtual destructor, even if it's trivial. This is because you will be deleting things through GameObject pointers.
- If it's necessary to distinguish the game objects, use a virtual method returning a 'type' value.
- As far as it's *not* necessary to use it, don't use that type value, but use other virtual methods that do meaningful things instead. Using the type value (and then generally casting to the subtype) should be considered a last resort. For instance (inventing details about your game freely):

  - Every object has a name that shows when you put the cursor over it. This is returned in name().
  - Events in the game may cause 'damage' an object. This only applies to some sorts of objects, so the default action on damaged() is to do nothing. Foo-objects, which respond to damage, override this with an actual action.
- However you implement the board, hide your exact implementation away in a class. (Don't take my code as an indication that you shouldn't use vector<> for this, that's definitely fine. I have a slight personal preference against vector< vector<> > here, but that's not too bad either.)
- Use shared pointers for the game objects.

  - Boost has a great and widely used implementation.
  - If you can't use shared pointers, control the lifetime of your game objects outside the Square class (say, in a master list of all game objects in the Board class), and then use raw pointers in the Square class.
  - If you do use shared pointers, and it's the first time you do, briefly read up on them first. They're not magic, you need to beware of certain things such as circular references.
- Depending on your needs, you may want to have a "backlink" in GameObject to the squares, or the coordinates of the squares, that contain pointers to that GameObject. This will allow you to easily remove objects from the board and move them around.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll be doing my object classes just like that. But I'm not sure about the board suggestion. I didn't really mention it but the objects move around in the map. How would I go about moving an object from one square to the next? Won't the object be deleted if I remove the pointer from one square before I add it to another? 

Updated first post with these notes.

Comment: (I assume you mean using smart pointers here, since otherwise you pretty much have full control/responsibility for deletion.) When you remove an object from a Square, you make a local smart pointer from the one in the Square vector. You then remove it from the vector, but the object is not deleted because you still have a local smart pointer. You can then insert that one into another Square's vector, and then let the local smart pointer go out of scope. I think if you try to actually write out the code you'll find that you don't need to do anything special -- this is the natural way to do it.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much, I think I can take it from here.